# Google Script: Could not find range to get data from Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get email via google app script. What I am doing is I get an alert email if a person's birthday is today. I have an google sheets which already have those data. But I am having a problem in few things. First, below is my code which I am running

[image]

```
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var birthdaysSheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName("Data");
var settingsSheet = activeSheet.getSheetByName("Settings");
var sendEmailTo = settingsSheet.getRange("B4").getValue();

function emailAlert() {


  if (turnOnEmailNotice.toLowerCase() == "no")
  { 
    Logger.log("The Email Notification is NOT turned ON. System will Exit.");
    exit 
  } 

  //Get the total number of filled row in the sheet.
  var currentRowAT = 2;
  var currentCellValueAT = "start";
  while (currentCellValueAT != ""){
    if (currentCellValueAT = birthdaysSheet.getRange("A" + currentRowAT).getValue() != ""){
    currentRowAT = currentRowAT +1;
    }
  }
  var birthdaysSheetLastRow = currentRowAT - 1;

  // Get today's Date (with Month, Date and Year)
  var today = new Date();
  var todayMth = today.getMonth()+1;
  var todayDate = today.getDate();
  var todayYear = today.getFullYear();



  for (k=2; k < birthdaysSheetLastRow + 1; k++)
  {
     var targetBday = new Date();
     targetBday = birthdaysSheet.getRange("P" + k).getValue();

     // If Birthday is not speicified, continue with the next row
     if (targetBday == ""){continue};

     var unadjTargetBday = new Date();
     var unadjTargetBdayMth = targetBday.getMonth()+1;
     var unadjTargetBdayDate = targetBday.getDate();
     var unadjTargetBdayYear = targetBday.getFullYear();
     var unadjTargetBday = targetBday;

     targetBday.setDate(targetBday.getDate()-daysInAdvance); // Calculating how many days in advance you want to trigger the notification. This is set in Settings Tab.
     var targetBdayMth = targetBday.getMonth()+1;
     var targetBdayDate = targetBday.getDate();

     if (targetBdayMth + " " + targetBdayDate == todayMth + " " + todayDate)
     {
       var targetBirthDateYearsOld = (today.getYear() - unadjTargetBday.getYear())-1900;
       prepareAndSendEmail(k, targetBirthDateYearsOld);       
     }
   } 
}

/*
*   This method actually prepares the HTML of the email body and send it out.
*/

function prepareAndSendEmail(row, targetBirthDateYearsOld)
{

  var firstName= birthdaysSheet.getRange("A" + row).getValue();
  var lastName = birthdaysSheet.getRange("B" + row).getValue();
  var emailAddress = birthdaysSheet.getRange("D" + row).getValue();
  var Birthday = birthdaysSheet.getRange("C" + row).getValue();

var message = "";

  message = message + "Hi all," + NEW_LINE + NEW_LINE;
  message = message + "Today is <B style=\"color:tomato\">" + firstName +  " " + lastName +  "</B>'s Birthday." + NEW_LINE + NEW_LINE;


 var tableHeader = "";
  tableHeader = tableHeader + "<table width=\"40%\" style=\"background-color:#FF8040;align:center;font-family:calibri,arial\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"0\" >";
  tableHeader = tableHeader + "<tr style=\"text-align:center;font-weight: bold;height:5px;\"> <td> </td> <td></td></tr>";
  message = message + tableHeader;

  var color = "GhostWhite";
  message = message + "<TR style=\"background-color:" + color + "\"> <TD style=\"text-align:left;font-weight: bold;\"> Birthday: </TD> <TD>" +  formatDate(targetCandidateBirthday) + "</TD>";
  message = message + "<TR style=\"background-color:" + color + "\"> <TD style=\"text-align:left;font-weight: bold;\"> Age: </TD> <TD>" +     targetBirthDateYearsOld + "</TD>";
message = message + "<TR style=\"background-color:" + color + "\"> <TD style=\"text-align:left;font-weight: bold;\"> Email: </TD> <TD>" +  targetCandidateEmailAddress + "</TD>";
}
```

**Question:**

1. What I am making mistake as I am having error getting range at `var firstName= birthdaysSheet.getRange("A" + row).getValue();`

   --**Error:** Range not found
2. I think my code to get age is also seems to be wrong.
3. If I am using only first row then age is coming as `undefined`.

Comment: Line 12: `exit`.  There is no `exit` in JavaScript.  You need to use `return;`  You have a variable name `turnOnEmailNotice` on line 9, but that name is never declared or set anywhere.  Right now you are getting individual cell values with the `getValue()` method.  That's slow.  It's better to get all the data in one action, then loop through the array of data.

Comment: I am getting one person's name only. I don't want whole column I am only getting a person's name at a time.

Comment: @SandyGood 
 
please check my updated question.

Comment: And I have used `turnOnEmailNotice` in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if your first loop would be better if structured like this:

```
//Get the total number of filled row in the sheet.
var currentRowAT = 2;
var currentCellValueAT = "start";
var thisRow, theBirthday = "";

var birthdayData = birthdaysSheet.getRange(1, 1, birthdaysSheet.getLastRow()); //Get all of column A data

for (var i=0;i<birthdayData.length;i+=1) {
  thisRow = birthdayData[i];
  theBirthday = thisRow[0];
  if (theBirthday === "") {
    var birthdaysSheetLastRow = currentRowAT - 1;
    break;  //Stop looping through the data
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved. I just ran the script in excel sheet. It worked. Didn't changed anything.

Thank You Guys for your help.